# Use wordpress json api to get posts where post title contains some characters

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-json-api

i want to get all posts that contains specific characters using json api plugin in wordpress, i successes to get post where title is equal to string "mytitle", using this, 
http://mysite/json=get_posts&post_type=my_type&title=mytitle , 
but i want to get all posts that contains mytitle string , 
can any one help ?